# Relation between some prime numbers and their sum

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, combinatorial-number-theory

Let $p$ and $q$ be two prime numbers less than $900$ billion. If $p + 6, p + 10, q + 4, q + 10$ and $p + q + 1$ are all primes, what is the greatest value that $p + q$ can take?

Can you help me to solve this problem (useful relations exist but I don't know about them)?

Comment: Take it as a generalization of "$p,p+3$ are both primes" (which implies $p=2$)

Comment: @reuns How did you get $+3$ in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$p+10$ is prime, so not a multiple of $3$, so $p$ can't be $1$ less than a multiple of $3$. Similarly $q$ can't be $1$ less than a multiple of $3$. $p$ and $q$ can't both be $1$ more than a multiple of $3$, since then $p+q+1$ would be a multiple of $3$. So one of them is a multiple of $3$, and since prime must be equal to $3$.

In fact $q$ must be $3$ since $p+6$ is prime. Now the conditions reduce to $p+4$ ($=p+q+1$), $p+6$ and $p+10$ must all be prime. There are lots of possible choices for $p$; you just need to find the largest such $p$ in the range given.

Comment: Note that since $p+4, p+6$ is a pair of twin primes, you can probably find a list to check them.

Comment: Yes, probably, or it doesn't take too long to search by computer, starting at 900 billion and working down.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A258088 is pertinent here (but doesn't go far enough to provide an answer).